# Scraping an HTML page that is still loading using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some information from a web page using R.  The only problem (so far) is that when I inspect the HTML object that was returned, I see that the key DIV element (from which I want to return data) has the message that it is loading.

The code I am using is below.

How can ensure that all elements on the web page have been rendered before harvesting the HTML.

```
library(xml2)
html <- xml2::read_html("https://www.holidayhouses.co.nz/")
lst_node <- xml_find_all(html, "//body/div[@class = 'MapView js-MapView']/h1")
lst_node
# returns <h1 class="LoadingMessage">Loading...</h1>
```

Thanks for any suggestions...

Comment: Two critical page resources are loaded via AJAX/XHR. You need to use RSelenium or use Developer Tools to identify the URLs and figure out how to use them. I built `curlconverter` for the latter (github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter)

Answer (score 0):

I am editing my answer as the two ideas might apply if you use the package `RSelenium`. It is not the fastest way for scraping, but it should do the job. What you can do with this package, is to use R to interact with your internet browser.

So once you use RSelenium to go tu the url, you can:

1. If you are confident that the div will load in a certain amount of time, then you can set some delay using Sys.sleep() before you save the div in lst_node
2. Iterating until lst_node!="Loading..." with a while loop

Comment: Thanks Dambo....once the first statment (ie. read_html) is executed....its gone...and there is nothing that sys.sleep can do.  Regarding the second option...its not a bad idea but each time I called read_html()....it will return the same result....